# Galactic motion and expansion

Tags: astrophysics

Is the milky way (and/or other galaxies) actually moving through space, or is it moving with space, i.e. moving with the expansion of space?  If its the latter, is the space between the stars in a galaxy also expanding?  If so then on what scale/s does the motion cease (if at all), and why?

Comment: Imagine a river flowing into a sea and carrying fallen leaves. Those leaves held together as a branch stay together despite of the current, but separate leaves flow apart into the vastness of the sea. So atoms, rocks, or galaxies are not expanding, but separate galaxies do fly apart per the Hubble law.

Answer (score 1):

The Sun is moving [368 ± 2 km/s](http://www.astro.ucla.edu/~wright/CMB-DT.html) relative to "the rest frame of space" as determined by the cosmic microwave background radiation. Note that the theory of relativity says that the laws of physics do not prefer one or another reference frame, and this is more saying "here's how we are moving relative to the stuff that happened to be nearby soon after the Big Bang;" space *itself* doesn't care *per se*.

The expansion of space does in fact happen on the tiniest of scales: but it happens with the tiniest of effects at those scales. So for example the space between the atoms in your body is slowly, slowly expanding -- but your electromagnetic forces holding you together easily overwhelm this expansion, holding you together. Similarly gravity overwhelms the expansion and holds the planet Earth together, and in fact the effect is still too weak to observe at the scale of a solar system or a galaxy or even a local cluster of galaxies -- this is why Andromeda Galaxy is headed straight for us in the Milky Way even though we are in different galaxies; the gravitational attraction overwhelms the expansion of space between these galaxies.

It is only as you go beyond the local cluster level that the steady expansion of space has a noticeable effect on the light that has traveled from these distant galaxies to us, making it noticeably redder than it would otherwise be.

Comment: Is Andromeda closing up specifically because of the gravity? Seems unlikely considering that the gravity without "the dark matter" can even hold one galaxy together.

Comment: I mean there is at least one prediction that we [already saw "first blood" 10 billion years ago](https://arxiv.org/abs/1306.6628) and that this upcoming collision is a "second pass", so the answer is probably "yes"--but it depends a lot on galactic history which we don't have a really great probe of.

Comment: So yes, if gravity is reverse proportional to the distance instead of squared distance. I like this much better than the "dark matter". Theories should be built to explain what we see, not the other way around like trying to find "dark matter" to explain the theory that we have.